# Is there a way to have different camera angles for different characters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm working on a 3D game for a school project where there are three selectable characters, all of different sizes, and I have written some code to make it so that the camera is attached to the character that was selected.

An issue that I came across is that the camera stays in the same position, regardless of which character is chosen which makes it slightly awkward picking a smaller character and having the view up too high or picking a bigger character and having the view too low.

I will mention that the way my character selection works is that once one is selected, it'll create a 'clone' of the prefab in the game scene, which makes it slightly complicated for me to experiment as I can only see changes while the game is running, making it difficult to save changes.

I have attached a CameraFollow script to the main camera 3 times, each as its own component, thinking it may have an effect, but it is still fixed in the same place regardless. I'll attach screenshots and the relevant scripts.

Character Selection Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CharacterSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] characters;
    public int selectedCharacter = 0;

    public void NextCharacter()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter = (selectedCharacter + 1) % characters.Length;
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void PreviousCharacter()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter--;
        if (selectedCharacter < 0)
        {
            selectedCharacter += characters.Length;
        }
        characters[selectedCharacter].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedCharacter", selectedCharacter);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Character Loading Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class LoadCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] characterPrefabs;
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    public TMP_Text label;

    void Start()
    {
        int selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter");
        GameObject prefab = characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        label.text = prefab.name;
    }
}
```

Camera Follow Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform player;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 offSet;
    void Update()
    {  
        transform.position = player.position + offSet;
    }
}
```

Using the script in 3 components under the main camera did not work, and I also tried to copy the 'clones' to the game scene, so I can access them without having to run the game, but with no success. What I find most frustrating is that the prefabs load up as clones once they are selected from the character selection menu, and I cant access them unless the game is running, which means I won't be able to save any edits. I am afraid that the same problem may arise when trying to add movements scripts to the characters once they have loaded in. I am not very experienced with Unity, having only worked with it for about 2 weeks now and my problem is too specific for me to find a tutorial on it.

If anyone could help and give an answer that is understandable to a beginner, especially regarding the whole clone situation and how to deal with it, that would be greatly appreciated.

[image: POV from a big character]
[image: POV from a medium-sized character]
[image: POV from a small character]

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple instances of the same CameraFollow script probably didn't work because each one would stomp on the other's change to `transform.position`, so in the end only the last script to execute `Update()` each frame would have its changes applied.

A different way to go about this is to have a single `CameraFollow` instance on your Camera, but have each character dictate the offset the camera should use. That way, when you load a character, you can update the offset accordingly.

What might this look like? Well, first you need a script you can attach to your characters (if you haven't got one already):

```cs
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This should be set to the required camera offset for this character
    [SerializeField] Vector3 offSet;
    public Vector3 OffSet
    {
        get
        {
            return offSet;
        }
    }
    
    // [...]
}
```

You also need a new method on `CameraFollow` to allow its fields to be updated:

```cs
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform player;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 offSet;
    void Update()
    {  
        if (player == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        transform.position = player.position + offSet;
    }

    // This will allow us to change what the camera is looking at
    public void SetFollowTarget(Transform player, Vector3 offSet)
    {
        this.player = player;
        this.offSet = offSet;
    }
}
```

Lastly, we can use this new property and method to ensure the camera is always tuned to the supplied character:

```cs
public class CharacterSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    // We'll need a reference to the CameraFollow script to change this, though
    // you could use a singleton or some other approach to get the reference
    [SerializeField]
    CameraFollow cameraFollow;
    
    // Let's change this to an array of Character to easily access their properties
    public Character[] characters;
    public int selectedCharacter = 0;

    public void NextCharacter()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter = (selectedCharacter + 1) % characters.Length;
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UpdateCameraForSelectedCharacter();
    }

    public void PreviousCharacter()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter--;
        if (selectedCharacter < 0)
        {
            selectedCharacter += characters.Length;
        }
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UpdateCameraForSelectedCharacter();
    }

    // [... (StartGame omitted for brevity)]

    // With the new property and method, it's a cinch to update the camera now
    private void UpdateCameraForSelectedCharacter()
    {
        cameraFollow.SetFollowTarget(
            characters[selectedCharacter].transform,
            characters[selectedCharacter].OffSet);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class LoadCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    CameraFollow cameraFollow;

    public GameObject[] characterPrefabs;
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    public TMP_Text label;

    void Start()
    {
        int selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter");
        GameObject prefab = characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        label.text = prefab.name;

        // In the same way, we can easily update the camera on scene load
        Character character = clone.GetComponent<Character>();
        cameraFollow.SetFollowTarget(
            character.transform,
            character.OffSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply but I've got a few questions regarding the information you have given me. First off, what would I have to drag into the Camera Follow field in the Character Selection Script component? Second, I'm not able to load into the Game Scene after clicking the play button on the Character Selection scene anymore, is there perhaps something that I've got to fill out myself? Third, I've attached the Character script which you gave me to each prefab in the Selection scene. Would a similar technique be used for movements (because of different speeds) and movesets? Thanks

Comment: Hi @RaffaeleOzunu, 1) You would drag your the Camera instance into the `cameraFollow` field. This should be the Camera that has the `CameraFollow` attached to it. 2) Sorry, you still need to keep the rest of our code, I just omitted untouched parts of your code with `// [...]` for brevity. All the changes are additive, none of the unrelated parts should be deleted. 3) Yes - for the immediate future, treat the `Character` script as where you put all the unique attributes of each character. Though as you develop more you may want separate components to define more complex behaviours.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. The code is running better but there are still some issues I'm finding. The first one is that, the camera is in the right place when the first character loads up, but while the game is running, I try to move the clone and the camera doesn't seem to be attached to it, the character just moves away. Another issue is that for the other two characters, this some errors come up (see image link) and I don't get the same view of their backs like I would with the first character. The camera may be too close because they aren't visible. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY96q.png

Comment: Nevermind, forget the whole thing about the other characters not appearing. I must've been stupid enough to turn off their prefabs in the Game Manager and just noticed now. The only problems that remain is getting the camera to move with the character and to somehow get rid of the errors in the screenshot, I'll try my very best to work on them, but I may need your take on it for some extra reassurance. Thanks again btw

Comment: Ah, the error in the CameraFollow is probably because it's using the `player` variable before it's been set. I've added a guard for that. For the other two errors, make sure you're dragging the camera (in the scene) onto the `cameraFollow` field for both the `CharacterSelection` and the `LoadCharacter` scripts. Otherwise they won't know what camera is being used. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Thank you with all of your help so far, I am getting no more errors and the camera is attached to the player, only thing to figure out now is how to rotate the Zoro prefab because he keeps facing the wrong way regardless of what I do to him. I'll see how that goes

Comment: I see! Well, I'm glad you've got most of the details ironed out now. If this answer solved your original question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left - that signals the question is solved. (Same thing for your newer question, if the answer there solves it.) If you're having difficulty with character rotation, you might need a separate question to get more attention on that specific issue.